# cluster analysis on heteroscedastic data

Tags: clustering, heteroscedasticity

I want to do a cluster analysis using a set of measures that are much more prone to error of measurement as you approach the low end of their distribution.  I have an intuitive sense that I should shrink the distances between items that occupy the clustering space where I know there is greater error of measurement. Distances between items in the space defined as you approach the low end of the distributions are much less meaningful than distances between items in the space defined by the high end of the distribution.

Does this make sense to anyone else, and is anyone aware of methods or approaches for dealing with this problem?